# App with wx gui is busy and crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

First of all sorry for my English.

I do measurements with my `Agilent`.
I wrote some high-level functions to do it simply.
And now I want to plot result while measurement in progress.
I use `wxPython` and `matplotlib`.

My code(simplified):

```py
class MyInstr():
    def __measurement(self, start, step, stop, plt, result):
        if plt:
            app = wx.PySimpleApp()
            app.f = MeasGraph(result)
            app.f.Show()
            def st(app):
                app.MainLoop()

        th = threading.Thread(target=st, args=(app,))
        th.start()

        for ...
            get_data():
                ...
                result.append(new_data)
                app.f.redraw_plot(result)

    def bsweep(self, start, step, stop, plt=True):
        result = {'info': {}, 'prim': [], 'sec': [], 'swp:' []}
        self.__measurement(start, step, stop, plt, result)


class MeasGraph(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, result):
        self.data = result
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Measurement Result')
        self.create_main_panel()

    def create_main_panel(self):
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.init_plot()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.panel, -1, self.fig)
        self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.Fit(self)

    def init_plot(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.primary = self.axes.plot([0], [0])[0]

    def redraw_plot(self, result):
        self.data = result
        self.primary.set_xdata(self.data['swp'])
        self.primary.set_ydata(self.data['prim'])
        self.canvas.draw()

def main():
    instr = MyInstr()
    instr.bsweep(0, -0.1, -5, plt=True)
```

It works fine with the exception of window with plot. It is busy and when I click on it my app crashes.

Thank you.

---

**UPD 1:** Ok, but I want to be able to run measurement several times, and I want to see all previous plots and current plot  at the same time.
For example:

```py
instr.bsweep(0, -0.1, -5, plt=True) # measurement (up to 5 Volts) and plot
```

And now I see that I need do this measurement up to 10 Volts. Thus:

```py
instr.bsweep(0, -0.1, -10, plt=True)
```

And I want to compare one plot with another.

But I can't do it, because previous plot (if it will be in a main thread) blocks my shell or my app.

Comment: One issue is that you're running the wx MainLoop in a thread, you need to run it in the main thread - you might find that changing that solves your problem